# click event only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image gallery with a css lightbox. Currently the image gallery is a masonry with lazyload. As the lightbox is a css only one all the images got loaded at the start. So I wanted to force a lazyload on it aswell. So I am trying to force a lazyload only if the image is getting used (clicked on the image in the masonry layout). After i get this working perfectly I can set the same kind of link on the previous and next icons in the lightbox.

But here is the problem. It only works the first time i click on a image. It does not matter wich image, but it only workes once :(

I tried several things but none seems to work.

But the issue remains.

Javascript jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#image-link").on('click', function() {
        var counter = $(this).data('target');
        $('.lazybox-' + counter).lazy();
    });
});
```

Html = the counter is to force the lazyload on the specific image

```html
<a id="image-link" href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" data-target="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
   <img class="lazy" src=/images/placeholder" data-src="<?php echo base_url($imageLocation); ?>" alt="<?php echo $selected_gallery . ' ' . $counter; ?>">
</a>
```

I would like to be able to use the javascript function more then once. If at all possible explain why it happend so I can learn, I am a true beginner if it comes to javascript.

Comment: Are you dynamically replacing the `#image-link` at any point?  And you only have one element on the page with the id of `image-link` I assume?

Comment: Try: `$(document).on('click', '#image-link', function(){`

Comment: @vsync I'm trying to get there with the comments.  If that's the issue (most likely it is), this is a duplicate.

Comment: *"Changing the jquery click() to on('click', function()"* - Can you be more specific about what you changed from and to?  `.on()` is not a magic wand.  If the element holding the event handler is replaced then it's going to fail for exactly the same reason as `.click()` did.

Comment: `click(function(){})` to `on('click', function(){})` is the same exact thing

Comment: No i have multiple #image-links on the page. Actualy every image has the same id. Thats why I give along the data-target

I forgot to mention I am a beginner at javascript

Comment: Id's must be unique or else only the first element will have the event so try giving them a unique id and use a class instead $('.class').on('click', function() {}); Also your "src" is missing quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I feel realy stupid. But the solution was pretty simple.

Don't use a ID #image-link but use a CLASS .image-link

Comment: Were you using the same ID more than once?

Comment: indeed I was :'(